# Centos failed to start Mysql Server

Tags: centos, mysql

Centos failed to start Mysql Server

## Error

[image: Error]

---

## Error while installing `mysql-devel`

[image: Error while installing mysql-devel]

---

## Closed port 3306

[image: Closed port 3306]

---

## iptables

[image: iptables]

---

Comment: I wish I could downvote this.

Answer (score 1):

You're pulling packages/dependencies from multiple repositories. Some packages might be getting pulled from EPEL others from Remi. That would explain IMG#2 which would explain IMG#1. Either EPEL or Remi, not both as you will have version/dependency mismatches.

As for port 3306 being closed, even if the packages were installed correctly without dependency mismatches, it's supposed to be localhost only by default, meaning either all applications working with MySQL have to be on the same server or you have to create a SSH tunnel to the server so that you can communicate with localhost or you have to change the address it is listening on and expose the database to outside connections (not recommended).